# Image button on the normal button

Tags: android, android-layout

Screenshot

[image]

I want to place the image button with the icon(in my `Screenshot` icon is not set. It's only for the demonstration) corner of a button as a part of the button.(Please see the `Screenshot`). But Always Image button place under the button. I want to place it on the button. I can't bring it to front using `bringToFront()` method. That does not work as expected. Is there any way to place image button as in my screenshot?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Btn" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_round" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use FrameLayout instead of Relative.

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv With using frame layout image button still in back. I have set elevation to the image button now. Now it appears on top. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just you need to add some elevation to the image button. After elevation, it will be displayed as posted in your screenshot.

Please refer below code for the same:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Btn" />

    <ImageButton
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Btn" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_round" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: With using frame layout image button still in back. I have set elevation to the image button now. Now it appears on top. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine in your code. Just use an elevation in your ImageButton. That's it.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="105dp"
android:layout_height="105dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Btn" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_round" />
```